# Background-image not displaying on just one mobile page

Tags: html, css

The background-image works on all my website's pages on desktop and all but one on  mobile. I'm trying to figure out why it won't display on just one of my mobile pages.

Here's the html for the page that it doesn't work on:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/Css/MPW.css">
</head>

<body class="pageContainer">
<header class="headerContent">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="navBarLeft">Website Name</li>
            <a class="navBarRight" href="contact.html">
                <li>Contact</li>
            </a>
            <a class="navBarRightCurrent" href="index.html">
                <li>Home</li>
            </a>
        </ul>
        <div id="headings">
            <h1 id="nameHeader">title</h1>
            <br>
            <h2 id="typeItH2"></h2>
        </div>
        <a id="readCv" href="#readCvJump">Read CV</a>
    </nav>
</header>

<div id="mainContent">
    <h3>CV</h3>
    <div class="cvSection">
        <h4 id="cvSectionHeadingFirst">Academic History</h4>
        ....
        ....
```

Then here's the html for the page that does work:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/Css/MPW.css">
</head>

<body class="pageContainer">
<header>
    <div class="headerContent">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <a class="navBarRightCurrent" href="contact.html">
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </a>
                <a class="navBarRight" href="index.html">
                    <li>Home</li>
                </a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>

<div id="contactForm">
    <h4 id="contactHeading">Contact Us</h4>
    ...
    ...
```

Here's the CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
from {
    opacity: 0;
}
to {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

}

```
@keyframes fadeInUp {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

nav li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

footer {
    background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
    height: 70px;
    padding: 65px 15% 40px 15%;
}

.headerContent {
    background-color: white;
    background: url(../Images/mainPhoto.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
        background: url(../Images/mainPhotoSmall.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    }
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 40px 10% 40px 10%;
}

#readCv {
    margin-left: 44%;
    padding: 12px 23px;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(246, 246, 244);
    color: rgb(159, 83, 59);
    border-color: rgb(159, 83, 59);
    border: 2px solid;
    width: 70px;
    text-align: center;
}

#readCv:hover {
    border-color: rgb(54, 53, 48);
    color: rgb(54, 53, 48);
}

#headings {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 30vh;
    width: 450px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#nameHeader {
    animation: fadeInUp 1.3s ease-in-out;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    background: rgba(246, 246, 244, .4);
    border-radius: 8px;
}

#mainContent {
    background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 15% 60px 15%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pageContainer {
    min-width: 700px;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

#contactForm {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 120px;
    margin: 0px 25% 20px 25%;
    width: 450px;
    padding: 50px 80px;
    background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
    border-radius: 6px;
}

#contactHeading {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'AlgreyaSans-Regular', 'Helvetica';
    animation: fadeInUp 1.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: fadeInUp 1.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

What I've tried:

- Loading a much smaller image for mobile devices.
- Compared the two headers to make them as similar as possible.
- Taking out content from the header to see if any of it was affecting the background image.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the `<header` tag versus the included `div`

Version 1: `<header class="headerContent">`

Version 2: `<div class="headerContent">`, with the `<header>` tag before that

i.e. that CSS class is assigned to two different elements

Comment: it makes no difference whether the class is on the header or the div, in fact it was originally on the div but then I tried to move it to the header to see if that would work.